# Bluetooth dongle not detected

Tags: bluetooth

Very frustrated. Have tried numerous solutions posted regarding Ubuntu not detecting Bluetooth dongle to no avail. I have tried Bluez, Bluetooth Manager and Blueman.

I am not a programmer. I have copy/pasted dozens of lines of code suggestions and still cannot get Ubuntu to detect the dongle. I do not know what to type in Terminal to get output to show.

I am on an older Acer laptop which once ran Windows 7, now solely running Ubuntu 18.04.

Please help.

I don't know if this helps...

[image: screenshot]

Here is output of lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:a133 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I didn't really understand the 2nd part and do not think I did it correctly:

```
journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-04-06 15:01:12 EDT. --
May 31 17:50:57 triumph dbus-daemon[1115]: [session uid=1000 pid=1115] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
May 31 17:50:57 triumph dbus-daemon[1115]: [session uid=1000 pid=1115] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
May 31 17:50:57 triumph systemd[922]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
May 31 17:50:57 triumph dbus-daemon[1115]: [session uid=1000 pid=1115] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calendar'
May 31 17:50:57 triumph dbus-daemon[1115]: [session uid=1000 pid=1115] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
May 31 17:50:57 triumph nautilus[4617]: g_key_file_load_from_file: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
May 31 17:50:57 triumph nautilus[4617]: Could not establish a connection to Tracker: Failed to load SPARQL backend: Key file does not have group “DomainOntology”
May 31 17:50:58 triumph nautilus[4617]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 31 17:50:58 triumph nautilus[4617]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
May 31 17:50:58 triumph nautilus[4617]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed

May 31 17:52:47 triumph org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1487]: [2268:2268:0531/175247.128775:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
May 31 17:55:04 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:08 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:22 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:26 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:31 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:31 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:33 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:35 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:37 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:37 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:41 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:41 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:43 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:46 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:48 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:49 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:51 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:52 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:53 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:55 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:57 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:58 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:55:59 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:56:00 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:56:03 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:56:05 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:56:06 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:56:07 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:56:08 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 2607:fea8:6920:8a4:be4d:fbff:fed4:6342.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:09 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:12 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:56:12 triumph systemd-resolved[628]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May 31 17:57:14 triumph wpa_supplicant[793]: wlp7s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with bc:4d:fb:d4:63:48 [GTK=TKIP]
May 31 17:57:33 triumph org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1487]: [2268:2268:0531/175733.446350:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
```

Comment: I know that this is off topic but if your computer is slow you might want to install another desktop environment like mate.

Comment: Please edit your post and paste the output of the following commands: With dongle plugged, enter this `lsusb` and paste output --- Next show us logs of what happens when pluging the dongle: display logs with `journalctl -f`, hit Enter key to mark where you start, plug-in the dongle, copy/paste the log output to your post. Thanks

Comment: @Budget Tech I appreciate the suggestion. Out of curiosity, why Mate as opposed to XUbuntu or LUbuntu?

Comment: @Melebius    As stated, I am not a programmer. I do not know how to apply code formatting.

Comment: Can you run `dmesg -w` with your dongle unplugged, and then plug it in and post what appears in the dmesg command after plugging in? Exit `dmesg` with Ctrl-C

Comment: @StephenKennedy Please use the {} button to add proper formatting when adding terminal output.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Thank you for adding text instead of screenshots! You don’t have to be a programmer to be able to [format your terminal text as code](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)! Just select it and press `Ctrl`+`K` or the `{}` icon. I’ve done it this time for you.

Comment: @StephenKennedy I recommended mate because it looks better than Xubuntu or lubuntu and it is really beginner friendly and there community is very helpful, also it was the distro I started with